# Conditionally formatting data in a grid

Tags: c#, object-oriented, sql, asp.net, formatting

I have telerik radgrid that has an SQL backend. What this function is doing is conditionally formatting the cells with in the radgrid. It checks each column to see if the min and max values are within range and the min and max values change depending on the value in the sample_hour column. My question, is there any more refactoring I can do to this function to make it cleaner and I was having an issue with when the `float.parse` hit a null value it would break so I put a tryparse and it works now but I'm not sure if that is the right thing to do.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Is it a GridDataItem
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            //Get the instance of the right type
            GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            //Check the formatting condition
            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "4hr YP")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.75f, 5.72f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 17.35f, 22.36f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 89.08f, 90.97f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["bud"], 3.12f, 40.76f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["cell_count"], 41.24f, 177.70f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["Viability"], 69.18f, 103.08f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 2.55f, 10.89f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 1.41f, 6.05f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.41f, 8.28f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.26f, 6.69f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.01f, 0.12f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 0.33f, 0.57f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.07f, 0.17f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], .005f, 1.15f);
            }
            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "YP Drop")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.39f, 5.45f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 13.75f, 20.74f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 94.07f, 85.93f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["bud"], 5.37f, 42.55f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["cell_count"], 79.91f, 448.77f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["viability"], 83.26f, 102.28f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"],2.99f, 7.77f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], -0.32f, 4.72f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 2.20f, 9.60f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -2.74f, 5.93f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], -0.02f, 0.22f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 0.33f, 0.57f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], -0.01f, 0.08f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 1.15f, 3.71f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "Cook Water")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 3.03f, 8.91f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], -0.77f, 1.96f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], -0.18f, 0.20f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], -0.021f, 0.02f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], -0.14f, 0.15f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.14f, 0.018f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], -0.015f, 0.02f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], -0.02f, 0.02f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.001f, 0.086f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 0.52f, 1.71f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "Thin Stillage")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.45f, 5.39f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 3.31f, 7.38f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], -0.09f, 1.01f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.10f, 0.23f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.33f, 0.59f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.14f, 0.41f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.02f, 0.38f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.39f, 1.71f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.06f, 0.21f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], -0.03f, 0.06f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "5 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.68f, 5.66f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 26.60f, 30.63f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 89.85f, 94.41f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 4.17f, 14.65f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 1.38f, 3.85f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 5.35f, 8.91f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], 6.16f, 14.03f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], -0.008f, 0.21f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 0.47f, 0.81f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.007f, 0.15f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], -0.25f, 1.68f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "10 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.49f, 5.41f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 24.51f, 29.82f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 90.39f, 94.39f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["bud"], 6.02f, 40.56f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["cell_count"], 75.22f, 264.35f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["viability"], 78.56f, 101.31f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 6.176f, 10.51f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.78f, 3.03f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 6.12f, 9.22f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], 6.88f, 12.02f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.008f, 0.29f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 0.59f, 0.94f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.016f, 0.174f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 0.09f, 2.90f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "20 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.25f, 5.12f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 17.58f, 22.53f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 89.43f, 94.60f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["bud"],-1.98f, 29.56f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["cell_count"], 116.58f, 352.18f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["viability"], 83.59f, 102.07f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 3.81f, 6.42f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.28f, 0.59f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 2.38f, 6.62f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], 2.14f, 6.88f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], -0.10f, 0.46f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.03f, 1.41f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.014f, 0.146f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 6.15f, 8.38f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "30 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.19f, 5.09f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 13.31f, 18.80f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 87.06f, 92.72f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 1.41f, 4.12f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.29f, 0.63f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], -0.22f, 1.53f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], 2.08f, 6.27f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], -0.00166f, 0.369f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.15f, 1.54f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.031f, 0.149f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 9.03f, 11.55f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "40 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.23f, 5.15f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 10.54f, 16.28f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 84.98f, 92.20f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 0.61f, 1.88f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.17f, 0.47f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.24f, 0.52f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], 0.06f, 4.87f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.0019f, 0.37f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.24f, 1.66f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.04f, 0.16f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 11.31f, 13.89f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "50 Hour")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.28f, 5.38f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 9.47f, 14.14f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 85.07f, 91.87f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], -0.013f, 0.97f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.1001f, 0.28f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.2207f, 0.57f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -1.19f, 2.23f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.0027f, 0.37f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.22f, 1.76f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], -0.060f, 0.27f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 12.88f, 14.94f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "Drop")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 4.44f, 5.46f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 10.01f, 13.48f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 84.28f, 92.83f);                 
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["flevel"], 88.10f, 94.81f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 0.086f, 0.46f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.087f, 0.17f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.23f, 0.59f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.53f, 0.74f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.0039f, 0.36f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.29f, 1.74f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.032f, 0.181f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 13.33f, 15.08f);
            }

            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "Beer Well")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 5.69f, 4.60f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 9.62f, 13.54f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"], 84.93f, 94.92f);        
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], -0.01f, 0.59f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 0.08f, 0.14f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.2008f, 0.58f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.31f, 0.576f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.016f, 0.354f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 1.27f, 1.69f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.0111f,0.2085f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], 12.98f, 15.15f);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetFormatting(TableCell cell, float minValue, float maxValue)
    {

            float value = 0;
            float.TryParse(cell.Text, out value);

            if (value < minValue || value > maxValue)
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                cell.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                cell.Font.Bold = true;
            }


    }
```

Comment: Regardless float parsing...move that wall of repetitive code to a data file (or at least, to a dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**SetFormatting Method**

Switching to `TryParse` helps suppress the exception but what do you want to do if `cell.Text` was null?  Do you want to color the cell or not?  The logic you currently have would color the cell upon a null value with `minValue` > 0.  Is that what you want?

My suggestion would be to use: `if (float.TryParse(cell.Text, out value))` or `if (!float.TryParse(cell.Text, out value))` accordingly to explicitly deal with how you want with null values rather than have it fall through the cracks and produce undesired effects.